Mongoose reassigning DocumentArray to filtered DocumentArray results in TS error
I'm working with mongoose and using a blog schema that looks like this:
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";

const BlogSchema = new Schema({
  author: {
    type: {
      _id: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
      },
      username: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
  },
  thumbnail: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: false,
  },
  date: {
    type: Schema.Types.Date,
    required: true,
  },
  reactions: {
    type: {
      likes: [
        {
          type: Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
        },
      ],
      dislikes: [
        {
          type: Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    _id: false,
    required: true,
  },
});

export const Blog = model("Blog", BlogSchema);


In my server.ts file, I have a route defined that handles blog liking and disliking:
router.post(
  "/blogs/:id/:action",
  checkForAuthentication,
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const blogId = req.params.id as string;
      const action = req.params.action as Action;
      if (!["like", "dislike", "unlike", "undislike"].includes(action)) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid Action" });
      }

      const blog = await Blog.findById(blogId).select("reactions");
      if (!blog) res.status(404).send({ error: "Blog Not Found!" });
      if (
        blog &&
        blog !== undefined &&
        blog !== null &&
        blog.reactions &&
        blog.reactions !== undefined &&
        blog.reactions !== null
      ) {
        const sessionUser = req.user as Express.User;
        const userId = sessionUser._id as unknown as ObjectId;
        const { likes, dislikes } = blog.reactions;

        blog.reactions.likes = likes.filter( // TS ERROR
          (likeId: ObjectId) => !likeId.equals(userId) // TS ERROR
        );
        blog.reactions.dislikes = dislikes.filter( // TS ERROR
          (dislikeId: ObjectId) => !dislikeId.equals(userId) // TS ERROR
        );

        switch (action) {
          case "like":
            blog.reactions.likes.push(userId);
            break;
          case "dislike":
            blog.reactions.dislikes.push(userId);
            break;
          case "unlike":
            break;
          case "undislike":
            break;
        }

        await blog.save();
        res.send({ message: "Action completed successfully" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid Blog Id" });
    }
  }
);

When I try to assign the blog.reactions.likes array to a filtered array of itself, two TypeScript errors pop up:
-- Under blog.reactions.likes --
Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentArray<{ prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }>': isMongooseDocumentArray, create, id, $pop, and 8 more.

-- Under (likeId: Types.ObjectId) => !likeId.equals(userId) --
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }, index: number, array: (Subdocument<...> & { ...; })[]) => value is any, thisArg?: any): any[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(likeId: Types.ObjectId) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }, index: number, array: (Subdocument<...> & { ...; })[]) => value is any'.
      Types of parameters 'likeId' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectId': _bsontype, toHexString, getTimestamp, inspect
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }, index: number, array: (Subdocument<...> & { ...; })[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): (Subdocument<...> & { ...; })[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(likeId: Types.ObjectId) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }, index: number, array: (Subdocument<...> & { ...; })[]) => unknown'.
      Types of parameters 'likeId' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Subdocument<ObjectId, any, { prototype?: unknown; cacheHexString?: unknown; generate?: any; createFromTime?: any; createFromHexString?: any; createFromBase64?: any; isValid?: any; }> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId'.ts(2769)

What's the correct way to filter these arrays without causing any errors? Thanks

You could try using lean to return a POJO and then update the blog with findByIdAndUpdate:
router.post(
    '/blogs/:id/:action',
    checkForAuthentication,
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            const blogId = req.params.id as string;
            const action = req.params.action as Action;
            if (!['like', 'dislike', 'unlike', 'undislike'].includes(action)) {
                res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid Action' });
            }

            const blog = await Blog.findById(blogId).select('reactions').lean();

            if (!blog) res.status(404).send({ error: 'Blog Not Found!' });
            if (!blog.reactions)
                res.status(404).send({ error: 'Reactions Not Found!' });

            const sessionUser = req.user as Express.User;
            const userId = sessionUser._id as unknown as ObjectId;
            const { likes, dislikes } = blog.reactions;

            const newLikes = likes.filter(
                (likeId: ObjectId) => !likeId.equals(userId)
            );
            const newDislikes = dislikes.filter(
                (dislikeId: ObjectId) => !dislikeId.equals(userId)
            );

            switch (action) {
                case 'like':
                    newLikes.push(userId);
                    break;
                case 'dislike':
                    newDislikes.push(userId);
                    break;
                case 'unlike':
                    break;
                case 'undislike':
                    break;
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(blogId, {
                $set: { likes: newLikes, dislikes: newDislikes },
            });

            res.send({ message: 'Action completed successfully' });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid Blog Id' });
        }
    }
);

